# Jetpack Compose Multitouch

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

**I want to implement these states:**

```
00 if no one is touching
10 if player 1 is only touching
01 if player 2 is only touching
11 if both player 1 and 2 is touching
```

There must also be a variable that takes note who touches first
P1. if Player 1 touched first
P2. if Player  2 touched first.

*Take note: if the state is 11 (both player 1 and 2 is touching)
If one removes his hand regardless who touched first, the left hand has the state who touched first.*

[image]

**Scenario:**

**Player 1 touched  (state is 10 takes note that player 1 touched)**

**Player 2 touched (now the state is 11)**

**Player 1 removed the touch ( now the state is 01 and P2) (player 2 is the first to touch)**

My problem is that it doesn't support multitouch. The state won't go to 11 even though I utilized my phone. What's the best method you know? Thank you.

```
import android.view.MotionEvent
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxHeight
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.ArrowBack
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.IconButton
import androidx.compose.material3.LinearProgressIndicator
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.ExperimentalComposeUiApi
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.pointerInteropFilter
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import com.fabian.twov01.R
import com.fabian.twov01.datasource.DataSource
import androidx.compose.runtime.*

@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun TwoPlayersScreen(navController: NavController) {

    var touchState by remember { mutableStateOf("00") } // "00", "10", "01", "11"
    var firstTouch by remember { mutableStateOf("") } // "", "P1", "P2"

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

//          Background Image
//        Image(
//            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.mainmenu_bg),
//            contentDescription = "Background Image",
//            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
//            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
//        )

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(5.dp)
        ) {

            // LIFE, STATS, NAME Row
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(color = Color.Magenta)
                    .weight(.6f), // Adjust the weight as needed
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
            ) {

                //Player 1 stats
                Column(
                ) {
                    Row(
                    ) {
                        //PLAYER ICON
                        Image(
                            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.exit),
                            contentDescription = "Exit Icon",
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .size(50.dp),
                            contentScale = ContentScale.Fit
                        )

                        Column(

                        ) {
                            //LIFE
                            LinearProgressIndicator(

                                progress = 0.5f,
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .padding(top = 1.dp)
                                    .height(25.dp),
                                color = Color.Green
                            )

                            Text(text = "Wins: 0")
                        }

                    }

                    Text(text = "Player 1")

                }

                //PAUSE AND PLAY
                Column(
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,

                    ) {
                    Text(text = "2 Player Mode")

                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.exit),
                        contentDescription = "Exit Icon",
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(50.dp),
                        contentScale = ContentScale.Fit
                    )

                    Text(text = "Best of 3")

                }


                //Player 2 Stats
                Column(
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End
                ) {
                    Row(

                    ) {

                        Column(
                            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End
                        ) {
                            //LIFE
                            LinearProgressIndicator(

                                progress = 0.5f,
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .padding(top = 1.dp)
                                    .height(25.dp),
                                color = Color.Green
                            )

                            Text(text = "Wins: 0")
                        }

                        //PLAYER ICON
                        Image(
                            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.exit),
                            contentDescription = "Exit Icon",
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .size(50.dp),
                            contentScale = ContentScale.Fit
                        )

                    }

                    Text(text = "Player 1")
                }



            }






            // Assuming this is the "STATE OF THE HAND BY DRAWABLES" Row
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(color = Color.Gray)
                    .weight(1.4f) // Adjust the weight as needed
            ) {
                // Player 1 control area
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .weight(1f)
                        .fillMaxHeight()
                        .background(Color.DarkGray)
                        .pointerInteropFilter { motionEvent ->
                            when (motionEvent.action) {
                                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                                    touchState = if (touchState == "00" || touchState == "01") "10" else "11"
                                    if (firstTouch == "") firstTouch = "P1"
                                }
                                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                                    touchState = if (touchState == "11") "01" else "00"
                                    if (firstTouch == "P1") firstTouch = if (touchState == "01") "P2" else ""
                                }
                            }
                            true
                        }
                )

                // Player 2 control area
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .weight(1f)
                        .fillMaxHeight()
                        .background(Color.LightGray)
                        .pointerInteropFilter { motionEvent ->
                            when (motionEvent.action) {
                                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                                    touchState = if (touchState == "00" || touchState == "10") "01" else "11"
                                    if (firstTouch == "") firstTouch = "P2"
                                }
                                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                                    touchState = if (touchState == "11") "10" else "00"
                                    if (firstTouch == "P2") firstTouch = if (touchState == "10") "P1" else ""
                                }
                            }
                            true
                        }
                )

            }
            // Debug Text - Displaying the current touch state and first touch
            Text("Touch State: $touchState, First Touch: $firstTouch")
        }
    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the two conditions that you have:

```
// Player 1
MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
    touchState = if (touchState == "00" || touchState == "01") "10" else "11"
}

// Player 2
MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
    touchState = if (touchState == "00" || touchState == "10") "01" else "11"
}
```

What this logic will to that

- when `touchState == "01"` and Player 1 touches, set `touchState = "10"`
- when `touchState == "10"` and Player 2 touches, set `touchState = "01"`

I think with that code, it is impossible that the `touchState` becomes `"11"`. 
 You can try to adjust your code as follows:

```
// Player 1
MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
    touchState = if (touchState == "00") "10" else "11"
}

// Player 2
MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
    touchState = if (touchState == "00") "01" else "11"
}
```